# No bundle URL present. Trying to run a simple react-native-navigation app

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Im just trying to run my project. Xcode builds it successfully. Just crashes when the application launches in the simulator.

This is the error the simulators displays and what xcode also shows me :

No bundle URL present.

Make sure you're running a packager server or have included a .jsbundle file in your application bundle.

Comment: have you started the packager ?

Comment: Yea, i run npm-start then do react-native run-ios in another tab. I also have tried just running react-native by it self. same thing shows up both ways. Ive been stuck on this all weekend. Its be very tedious.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for above issue is the URL for main.jsbundle returned as null.

You might need to change the code in AppDelegate.m as follows

```
#ifdef DEBUG
   jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.120.40:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
 #else
   jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
 #endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, tried to figure it out whole day.
Deleting /build folder or generating main.js didn't help.

Solution was: run command "npm start" in the main folder of my project.

The initial error is actually that dev server is not running :)

Let me know if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`rm -rf ios/build/; kill $(lsof -t -i:8081); react-native run-ios`

it worked for me.